# Python: Elements of list

Tags: python, list

```
row = list_of_rows[0] **#row 0 of list**
timestamp = row[0][:20]
value = row[0][43:48]
print(timestamp + ": " + value)
```

if i change the line to :

```
row = list_of_rows[10] **#row 10 of list**
timestamp = row[0][:20]
value = row[0][43:48]
print(timestamp + ": " + value)
```

How can I do this codeblock for each row of the list? I tried with a for-loop but it don`t worked..

Comment: Why `for` loop does not work? if you are writing `for row in list_of_rows:` and then writing the next 3 lines inside the loop it will not work?

Comment: add your for-loop code so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi Gerry, welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions, it's helpful to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to best assist with helping your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop will definitely work:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_rows) - 1 ):
    row = list_of_rows[i] 
    timestamp = row[0][:20]
    value = row[0][43:48]
    print(timestamp + ": " + value)
```

Comment: Omit the `- 1` in the `range()`: `range(len(list_of_rows) - 1)` will omit the last row, because `range(n)` will iterate over `0,1,..., n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly iterate over the `list_of_rows` with a for loop.

```
for row in list_of_rows:
    timestamp = row[0][:20]
    value = row[0][43:48]
    print(timestamp + ": " + value)
```

Comment: How can i directly convert the String "value" in a Integer "Value"?

Comment: Use `int(value)`. To be safe, you can invoke `value.isnumeric()` to check that `value` is actually a number.

Comment: What can I do if the value is not a number?

Comment: You could do `value = int(value)` to overwrite your string value with the int.
_If the value is not a number, then you cannot convert it to an int_.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it in 1 line!

```py
[print(row[0][:20] + ": " + row[0][43:48]) for row in list_of_rows]
```

Comment: IMO this isn't the best usage for a list comprehension, unless the aim is to write it on one line :) This will end up creating a list of `None`s , which will never be used. List comprehensions would be good if you are actually extracting values from each row, e.g. getting the timestamp and value in a list.